# Resize div according to window size and zoom

Tags: html, css

I have a div i need to resize dynamically, but i cant seem to make it work when i zoom in a webpage.

```
<div style="background-color:red">
    Result screen small
</div>
<div style="background-color:green;height:370px;overflow:scroll">    //ignore static height
    stretch even when zoomed
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a6jscb6r/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/a6jscb6r/2/
I want to keep the lower div (green one) completely inside the browser window, thought the content inside the green div can be scrollable

Can i resize it dynamically so when i zoom, the div resizes itself?

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/a6jscb6r/3/

moved your styles outside

use `height:calc();`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.head {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}
.cont {
  background-color: green;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">Result screen small</div>
<div class="cont">stretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even
  when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch
  even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when
  zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch
  even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when
  zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomedstretch even when zoomed</div>
```